# Flask-HttpAuth and Flask-Login

Tags: authentication, flask, flask-login

I am creating a small REST service. I am looking for different authentication methods.
For sites I used the module Flask-Login. It seems the session authentication. The module Flask-HttpAuth provides the http and digest authentication methods. I am little bit confused.
Do they complement each other?
What is better to use for what is a reason?

Thank you.

Answer (score 54):

For a REST service you do not need Flask-Login. Typically in web services you do not store client state (what Flask-Login does), instead you authenticate each and every request. Flask-HTTPAuth does this for you.

You would use both only if you have an application that has a web component and a REST API component. In that case Flask-Login will handle the web app routes, and Flask-HTTPAuth will handle the API routes.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Flask-HTTPAuth.

Comment: I looked your report about REST. It seems I should always send login password to. I 've found about session authentication. I hope it exists. I develop my bicycle to understand what I need exactly. Sorry but your examples were not enough for me. I will reread them later.

Comment: Yes, for an API it is pretty normal to send authentication with every request. You can use user/password, or also tokens, which offer more security, since a leaked token can be revoked. I show both approaches in my blog posts.

Comment: Hmm, the author of one of the libraries himself took the time to provide an answer and @viktor.likin did not even bother to accept or upvote the answer.  Thanks Miguel Grinberg for providing insight and please accept my humble vote.

Comment: Great answer! I literally just asked this exact question on your blog @Miguel... Question though. When using a web login form, would you still use the same login route? eg /api/v1/login

Comment: You shouldn't have a `/api/v1/login` route at all. Authentication for the API routes can be handled with a decorator directly in the routes.

Comment: @Miguel I'm a bit confused by that. My /api/v1/login (or whatever I call it) is what I would hit with my user/pass once to get back a token, no? Then I use that token in all future REST calls...

Comment: @SJoshi: sorry, I don't think of that as a login, that's why I misunderstood you. So you have a "get-token" route for your API, and you are asking if you can use that for the web-based login form? The method to submit the credentials will be different, you will probably use JSON for the API, and a standard form encoding for the web app. The result is also different. For the API you return a token, for the web app you need to record the logged in state in a user session, because you can't easily make the browser send a token, but it is easy to make it send a cookie.

Comment: You can write the same token you use for the API into a cookie if you want, but still, the behavior is pretty different, so you may be better off moving the token generation to a common module that both the web app and the api can access. Or just let Flask generate a user session and use Flask-Login for the web app, leaving tokens just for the api.

Comment: @Miguel.  Can you elaborate on your answer to @SJoshi?  Why is using the get-token route not a viable method for logging in a user?  Why not build a login form that triggers a fetch request to get-token?  If the username and password are correct the view/route returns the token that can then be used to access protected routes. If the credentials are wrong, a token isn't returned.  Since the token can be stored client side in a javascript variable and then sent on subsequent api requests why is that not a viable way of logging in a user? I'm thinking of using this api for a Vue single page app.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup **Basic Auth** for Flask in a very simple way, without further modules, using **decorators**.

Take a look at: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/.

With **flask-restful**, just add `method_decorators = [required_auth]` to the `Resource` class attributes.

You can extend the snippet above, to allow for example user retrieval from a **database**.

Note that in a REST architecture, requests are [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Stateless): you don't use sessions, but send identification tokens along with every request (see http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html).

Comment: I agree with you. I have been looking for a ready solution. I am able to do own by myself you have described. It seems it should exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they complement each other.

You can also take a look at Flask-security, an all-in-one lib:

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/

> - Session based authentication
> - Role management
> - Password encryption
> - Basic HTTP authentication
> - Token based authentication
> - Token based account activation (optional)
> - Token based password recovery / resetting (optional)
> - User registration (optional)
> - Login tracking (optional)
> - JSON/Ajax Support